# Is there a way to obtain Youtube's real location urls using any available package?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, youtube, video-player

Is there a way to obtain Youtube's real location urls using any available package?

I'm trying to use VideoPlayer in flutter to play youtube videos within my app alongside videos on other platforms. To be able to use youtube with the Video Player package i have to use VLC to go to the videos codec and obtain the 'real' url(youtube.com => googlevideos link).

This would take a long time to do this for a list of youtube links and so i was wondering if there were any packages which allow you to do this?

Comment: Have you considered utilizing one of the Youtube Player packages out there for Flutter (like this: https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter)? If the issue is that other sites videos wouldn't play in their widget, you could just do a simple check to see if it's a YT video or not and then decide which widget to show.

Comment: You have given me an idea for something with that suggestion but i'm really looking for what i suggested as I will be using a range of videos from different platforms and want to be able to send them all to Video Player package. 

Yeah i see your point with checking to see if it is a YT video or not to show which widget. Ill have a look at it but still wondering if there is anything avaliable like mentioned.